# Passing arguments to ReturnNew with googlemock

Tags: googlemock

How can I mock a method that returns a new object whose constructor takes one of the method's arguments as an argument of its own?

```
// ObjectA::ObjectA(MockedObject arg1, ObjectB* arg2);
// ObjectA* MockedObject::MockedMethod(ObjectB* arg);
ON_CALL(mocked_object, MockedMethod(_))
    .WillByDefault(ReturnNew<ObjectA>(mocked_object, new ObjectB()));
```

In the above example, rather than using `new ObjectB()` as the argument for `ReturnNew<ObjectA>()`, I would like to use the `_` argument originally passed to `MockedMethod`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd just use [`WithArg`](http://code.google.com/p/googlemock/wiki/CheatSheet#Composite_Actions) and [`Invoke`](http://code.google.com/p/googlemock/wiki/CheatSheet#Using_a_Function_or_a_Functor_as_an_Action) with a lambda rather than `ReturnNew` in this case:

```c
ON_CALL(mocked_object, MockedMethod(_))
    .WillByDefault(WithArg<0>(Invoke(
        [&mocked_object](ObjectB* b) { return new ObjectA(&mocked_object, b); })));
```

Comment: I can't use C++11, so I just Invoked a regular function. Thanks!